# better way to write def __str__(self) in django model

Tags: django, string, methods

I am writing a django app. I'm curious if there is a better way of writing the python "magic method" `__str__()` that returns a string representation of any object. Currently, following the Django docs I find that you can do the following...

```py
class Todo(models.Model):
  firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  secondName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  
  def __str__(self):
    "%s %s" % (self.firstName, self.secondName)
```

Fine and dandy but if I have 8, or even more fields, then it gets kind of annoying to do this. First I find myself counting how many fields I want and make sure to write out `%s` that many times just to then write out `self.` the same amount of times and this really sucks.

I was hoping to if anyone knows of easier ways of writing this out and if there are what are the differences. I haven't been able to find another method online so I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python >=3.6, then you can use f-strings.

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.firstName} {self.secondName}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that f strings are fast and I am using Python >= 3.6 so I will begin to use this instead of %