# How can I override __str__ in models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Apologies if this is a silly question, I am pretty new to python and django.

I am following along with a django tutorial, and we are creating a fake movie site that lists movies by genre, title, etc.

I am currently trying to override the `__str__` function in the models.py file, so rather than displaying Genre (1), it displays the actual genre (ex. "Action").

Here's how my models.py looks currently:

```
from tkinter import CASCADE
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    release_year = models.IntegerField()
    number_in_stock = models.IntegerField()
    daily_rate = models.FloatField()
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

However, vscode is underlining the

```
def __str__ (self):
```

When I hover over it, it tells me:

> **str** does not return str pylint(E0307: invalid -str- returned

I tried looking at other solutions, but I could not find one that seemed to match my scenario, so I do apologize if this has been solved elsewhere, and I am too incompetent to understand the problem.

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Not overly familiar with your setup but seems like it's not recognising the field as returning a string, try wrapping the return with `str` - `return str(self.name)`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63665666/better-way-to-write-def-str-self-in-django-model

Comment: The f-string solution from that link was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has a couple of good illustrations of why it's important to understand your code before you rely too heavily on IDEs and tools like `pylint`. I've two suggestions:

1. The `pylint` error is just a warning to indicate that your code *might* have a problem - it is not an absolute fact. The `E0307` [error says](https://pycodequ.al/docs/pylint-messages/e0307-invalid-str-returned.html):

   > Used when a `__str__` method returns something which is not a string.

   It would be more accurate if it had said "when the `pylint` checker cannot be sure that you're returning a string". In this case, it's because it doesn't recognise that a Django `CharField` will in fact return a valid string instance. Your existing `__str__` method would work perfectly fine if you ran the code - regardless of what `pylint` thinks.

   You can work around this by forcing the return value to look like a string, e.g., with:

   ```py
   return str(self.name)
   ```

   or

   ```py
   return f"{self.name}"
   ```

   But it would be equally valid to [disable the check](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html#block-disables) for this line in pylint, *with the understanding* of why it reported the error. Just applying a fix found on Stack Overflow without understanding the issue is going to make it hard to debug your code in future.
2. There is a second, completely unrelated issue in your code which will cause you problems later, and that is this line:

   ```py
   from tkinter import CASCADE
   ```

   I am pretty confident that this has been inserted by your IDE, without your explicitly adding it, because you tried to use `CASCADE` in your `ForeignKey`. This is the IDE trying to be helpful - unfortunately it has imported something completely useless, that can [cause you problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980260/deploying-django-for-beginners-app-to-heroku-fails-with-modulenotfounderror-n) when you try to deploy your code.

Both of these highlight an important principle: don't rely on IDEs or linters. They are not a substitute for understanding your own code.

Comment: If I had the reputation, I would upvote this. Yes, I am definitely not retaining everything I'm learning in the codewithmosh tutorial, and I plan to read the documentation as I go along. My current method is to run through the entire python+django tutorial and follow along, apply small fixes where it's needed, then go back through a second time, and read documentation for each implementation.

Comment: Also, you are correct, the IDE did add that import when I used an on_delete argument, and I have removed it, good lookin' out!